# tools and ETLs for migrating data benchmarking - from shapefile to SQL SERVER

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, spatial-etl

i need to migrate my shapefiles to my database SQL SERVER, and i don't know what's the best tool or ETLs to choose, i already tried FME Desktop and i succeded to load the shapefiles on my db, but while searching i found other tools (like : artend, data migration tool kit, ETL integrator, Scriptella ...). Now i am confused, i don't know what to choose amoung many open source and licenced solution. Plz help.

Comment: Not really sure what the question is since you had success with FME (which is an excellent tool), but you could try the Shapefile Loader that comes with [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/sql-server-2008-spatial-tools.aspx).

Comment: What is wrong with FME Desktop? - We use it exclusively for moving large amounts of data [CAD/DGN or Other formats] into Oracle/SQL Server on daily basis. It is worth the purchase  and support responsive - first class service.

Comment: FME Desktop is not free and the trial period is too short.
i tried the shapefile uploader but the data was not uploaded in my database, also i found on the internet that the shapefile uploader do not deal with large amount of data. and since am working as a trainer on the agency of cadastrial data and cartography i need an excellent tool (preference open source) for moving data. 
Thank you

Comment: we have 30,000 cad files and 40,000 shapefiles all loading into oracle without issue from suppliers ftp site. Are you using Workbench or the universal translator? FME can be a steep learning curve for the untrained.

Comment: am generating workbench

Answer (score 2):

try to use open-source program [brigantine](http://code.google.com/p/brigantine/) to migrate shapefiles to SQL SERVER